# "Nothing is available, is anything?" Tag questions for negative sentences

Tags: syntax, tag-questions

I wasn't taught how to form a tag question when the main sentence involves "no".  Is it grammatical to say

> There's no problem with the car, is there?
>
> There's no apples left in the carton, are there?
>
> The poor man has nowhere to go, does he?
>
> Nobody cares about it, does anybody?
>
> It has nothing to do with the incident, does it?
>
> Nothing is as precious as unobtainium, is anything?

(Some of the above examples might not sound natural.  It would be great if you could suggest me better alternatives.)

Comment: Thought this might be interesting for you: [English grammar – Tag questions](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/tag-questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Original Poster has the right idea about the grammar here. When we have negative sentences, the question tags *must* be positive, not negative.

One small, but important point though: usually, we can only use basic *personal* pronouns in question tags (*I, she, he, it, we, you, they, there*). We don't normally use compound pronouns such as:

- *anybody/anyone/anything*
- *somebody/someone/something*
- *nobody/no one/nothing*.

With the words ending in *-body* or *-one*, we normally use the pronoun *they*:

- **Somebody** applied for the job, didn't **they**?
- **Nobody** applied for the job, did **they**?
- Not just **anyone** can apply, can **they**?

If we know that we are only thinking about males or females we very occasionally use *he* or *she*, but this is quite rare.

When we use the pronouns ending in *-thing*, we normally use the personal pronoun *it* in the tag:

- **Nothing** went wrong, did **it**?
- **Anything** could happen, couldn't **it**?
- **Something** exciting happened, didn't **it**?

**The Original Poster's examples**

The Original Poster's examples are all fine apart from the ones using the pronouns *nobody* and *nothing*. These would be better like this:

> Nobody cares about it, do they?
>
> Nothing is as precious as unobtainium, is it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the car, is there?

There is/are no apples left in the carton, are there?

The poor man has nowhere to go, does he?

**Nobody** cares about it, do **they**?

It has nothing to do with the incident, does it?

**Nothing** is as precious as unobtainium, is **it**?

---

**Nobody** has been told, have **they**?

**Everybody** is ready to leave now, aren't **they**?

Open the door, **will** you? ( Won't you /Can you/ Can't you) *Imperatives*

**Let's** (not) go there today, **shall** we?

She almost **never** studied, did she?

I don't believe **you**'ve paid for it yet, have **you**?

**This/ That** suit is expensive, isn't **it**?

I'm right, aren't I?

She **scarcely** cares, **does** she?

Comment: Nothing is as precious as unobtainium, **isn't** it?

Comment: @MAKZ *Unobtanium is the most precious thing, isn't it?*  Mrt's version is correct as written.

Comment: @JasonPatterson my mistake. +1

Comment: @MRT Your answer is quite good, though it could be even better if you add more information about the usage. Also, it looks like you copied those examples from a book or something (in which case you should cite your source properly). I couldn't find the book, but I found [this](https://issuu.com/hazirlik/docs/04.-tag-question--36---10.01.2004-).

Comment: "There's no apples" is in common use, even though some people object to it. I would not "correct" it myself.